# Turtlebot Start

Tags: ros, turtlebot, robot-calibration

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am building my own Turtlebot, and I have started without the image provided on ros.org.
There is mention of calling Turtlebot Start. This does not work. When looking for how to set it up, I am told that I should use the bash install and specify my wireless interface. What is happening there? Why do I need to do this?

Also, later, when I am performing gyro calibration, the two values go into the turtlebot.launch file. Are those values being used if I place them into /etc/ros/electric/turtlebot.launch or /turtlebot_bringup/upstart/turtlebot.launch?

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12607/turtlebot-start/) by [osuairt](https://answers.ros.org/users/1049/osuairt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 69 on 2012-01-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The turtlebot install script sets up an upstart job that runs the basic turtlebot launch file when your wireless is connected.

If you don't do this install step, you should instead run `roslaunch turtlebot_bringup minimal.launch` to start your robot.

When you calibrate your gyro, the calibration settings should go into the launch file that you use to start your robot. On a normal turtlebot, this is /etc/ros/electric/turtlebot.launch

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2012-01-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2012-01-13**:
calibration isn't supported with minimal.launch. you should either run the install script, put your calibration in /etc/ros/electric/turtlebot.launch, and use that to start your robot, or make your own copy of turtlebot.launch with the calibration and use that.

**Comment by [osuairt](https://answers.ros.org/users/1049/osuairt/) on 2012-01-12**:
Thanks for getting back to me. But in my case I run "roslaunch turtlebot_bringup minimal.launch" where do I place the calibration values then?

**Comment by [osuairt](https://answers.ros.org/users/1049/osuairt/) on 2012-02-24**:
I've gone about trying to setup the upstart, but I get the following behavior. http://answers.ros.org/question/12933/turtlebot-upstart-install-failure, resulting in missing topics etc.